# New page in rtf MS Word php

Tags: php, ms-word, rtf

I'm generating some rtf files using PHP. First, I generate 3 types of file, multiple variantons of each type (let's say bronze, silver and gold - I generate 3x bronze file, 5x silver and 2x gold). I want to merge all files of same type - all bronze files into one rtf file, all silver files into one silver file and all gold files into one gold file.

```
function merge_files($dir, $level, $type) {
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $files = glob("$dir/*$level*.rtf"); 
    if (count($files) > 0) {
        // open new file
        $filename = "$type-$level.rtf";
        if (!($out = fopen("$dir/$filename", "wb"))) { return false; }

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if (!($in = fopen($file, "rb"))) { return false; }
            /*while ($line = fgets($in)){
                fwrite($out, $line);
            }*/
            fwrite($out, fread($in, filesize($file)));
            fclose($in);
            unlink($file);
        }
        fclose($out);
    }
    return true;
} else {
    return false;   
}
```

}

When I check in source code, it appends all files into one but when I open it in MS Word, it shows only first file and not others. I thought that maybe MS Word doesn't show it because there must be some MS Word page separator / page breaker to show it all in MS Word.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to create a 'container' RTF group. The container RTF group would begin with '{\rtf1 ' and end with the closing '}'.  You would insert all RTF strings into this container RTF group. Example:

{\rtf1 {first rtf ....}{second rtf ....}{third rtf...} }

Word would then show all the above three RTF one after another.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really answer to the question, but it is answer to how I solve the problem. I google it a bit more and find out, that if I want plain rtf easy to read source and to customize source, I must save it in WordPad, instead of MS Word, because Word adds a lot of (for me) useless code, understanding just to Word. On the other hand, WordPad saves it plain and simple and then it is easy to append one rtf file to another.